# Flash notice text change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created `Posts` model and I want to change flash notice text when model is saved or updated.

How I can do that?
Thank you!

Comment: Please read about how flash messages work in rails. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash & http://travisonrails.com/2008/08/17/working-with-the-flash-hash would be a good start.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/plataformatec/responders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in your controller action, where you call `Post` methods, e.g.:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def create
    if Post.create(params)
      flash.notice 'Post saved'
    else
      flash.alert 'Post not saved'
    end
  end
end
```

It's best to keep your models isolated from the controller and controller methods such as `flash`, and set those in the controller instead.